# spark sql issue:join tables on first matched rows: rank() not working

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have to write below query using spark java API

```
select * from (
select u.*,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY u.imsi,u.[uplink_ip_string] ORDER BY u.uplink_start ASC) AS [RANK1] ,
from uplinkonly u,downlinkonly d
where u.imsi=d.imsi
and u.[uplink_ip_string]=d.[uplink_ip_string]
and u.[downlink_port]=d.downlink_port
and d.downlink_start!='0'
and (cast(u.uplink_start as bigint) -cast(d.downlink_start as bigint))< 25000
and (cast(u.uplink_start as bigint) -cast(d.downlink_start as bigint))>-25000
)a  where  RANK1=1"
```

but the spark is throwing the error

```
"Could not resolve window function 'rank'. Note that, using window functions currently requires a Hive Context"
```

What are the other options I can use to get my desired output?

Can I achieve it by iterating two RDD one for uplink and other for downlink?

Comment: Well the error says all and I believe that I have already answered questions like this before.

Comment: Ia there any other way i can achieve ranking funtionality in query